# Webpack import React component from directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, javascript-import

I have a problem. I made my project with create-react-app and I this is basically my structure:

```
src
├── app
│   ├── index.js
│   └── …
├── navigation
│   ├── index.js
│   └── …
└── …
```

My app/index.js

```
import App from 'app/App';

export default {
  App
};
```

My navigation/index.js:

```
import Navigation from 'navigation/Navigation';

export default {
  Navigation
};
```

The problem is that I can easily import from directory like:

```
import { App } from './app';
import { Navigation } from '.navigation';
```

The problem is that importing `Navigation` works as expected and importing `App` doesn't work. When I import App like above I get `'app' does not contain an export named 'App'` and if I try importing it like this:

```
import App from './app';
```

I get an object like this `{App: function(){}}` and if I render it like `<App.App />` it works as expected. Only difference is that `App` is class component and `Navigation` is function component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have single import in your file you can use:

```
export default FileName
```

If you have multiple imports you can use:

```
export { FileName1, FileName2}
```

Incase you want to export certain file as default from multiple files exported you can use:

```
export {default as FileName1, FileName2}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're exporting via a weird object-like syntax:

```
export default {
  Navigation
}
```

You need:

`export default Navigation`

Edit: pasting my comment below here with better formatting

You can only have one default export (even that's optional), but there's no limit to the total number. You can have:

```
// exports.js
export const a = 1
export const b = 2
export function exportTest () {}
// then a default
export default a
```

But - importing non-defaults happens only with the bracket syntax, let's say you want to import b which is a non-default export, you would need to use:

```
import { b } from 'exports' 
// or:
import { b as localName } from 'exports'
```

While you can import a default without the brackets and give it any name:

```
import whatever from 'exports'
console.log(whatever) // prints 1, as const a = 1 in exports.js
```

See [2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html) for more...

Comment: What if I want to export mutliple components?

Comment: You can only have one `default` export (even that's optional), but there's no limit to the total number. You can have:


`
// exports.js
export const a = 1
export const b = 2
export function exportTest () {}
// then a default
export default a
`
But - importing non-defaults happens with the bracket syntax, let's say you want to import b which is a non-default export:
`
import { b } from 'exports'
// while you can import a without the brackets:
import whatever from 'exports'
console.log(whatever) // prints 1
`

See http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html for more...